# Eliminar "," na primeira e ultima linha de um CSV

Tags: script, csv, shell-script

Tenho um csv que é exportado assim:

```
+++ Host - Begin +++,,
Name,Description
test1,abc2
test2, abd3
+++ Host - End +++,,
```

Como faço para obter este resultado?

```
+++ Host - Begin +++
Name,Description
test1,abc2
test2, abd3
+++ Host - End +++
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente o **sed** resolveria de uma forma simples esse exemplo que você deu:

```
sed s/,,//g
```

Supondo que o formato do texto seja:

```
+++ Host - Begin +++,,
Name,Description
test1,abc2
test2,abd3
+++ Host - End +++,,
```

Removendo todos os ",," do texto:

```
cat meuarquivo.csv | sed s/,,//g
# ou
sed s/,,//g meuarquivo.csv
```

Comment: Esqueci de perguntar, você está usando Windows ou Linux?

Comment: estou a usar Windows, já resolvi o problema em questão. quando corro o comando, no terminal o ficheiro aparece-me sem os tais ",," mas não grava as alterações no ficheiro

Comment: Depois você precisa salvar o resultado do output, talvez adicionando o > no final do comando resolva: sed s/,,//g meuaquivo.csv > novoarquivo.csv